# html error: I say top:0% and left:0% yet there is a blank padding in the browser

Tags: html, css

Alright this is probably a newbie question but it is very much frustrating me. I clearly say in the style tags that the top blue bar needs to be snug against the top and the two side panels need to be snug against the sides.

Yet for some reason it has taken the liberty of inserting a blank white space around my html.

Here is the link: http://popularn.com/nate/error.html

See that white space on the left and at the top?

Even when I say top:0% and left:0%, it *still* doesn't work. It's like it's laughing at me and I've had enough. It's like it is starting the document at top:2% and left:2% and there's nothing I can do...

Comment: +1 "It's like it's laughing at me", know that feeling;) The Webdeveloper-Console (F12 in most browsers and ctrl+shift+i in opera) is your friend! Use it to examine every element, which could be causing the trouble, in most cases you will find the error then.

Answer (score 4):

remove margin from the body, set top left to 0, and off course don't forget the position attribute

```
 html,body{padding:0; margin:0;}
 #someElement{position: absolute; top:0; left:0}
```

also - 
putting `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;` to the `body` is like doing nothing
and the `position` of the `#top_menu` should be `position: fixed` and not `fixes` which has no  meaning

Comment: Thanks, do you know why it was automatically inserting padding? On other html files I've made it didn't do that...

Comment: this is the default behaviour. almost every site I've ever done started with `html,body{padding:0; margin:0;}` on the css

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have a set of default styles which are known as 'User-agent styles'. These are a generic set of CSS rules that it applies to elements. You know when you put a H1 in a page, and it appears big, and in bold? These are those styles.

The base elements in your pages are all styled with these UA rules. Body, HTML, div, etc - they all have a small amount of padding on them, which is where this is coming from.

Consequently, it's good practice to **always use a CSS reset**, when you are developing beyond basic styles. There's a couple of good ones I'd recommend. As CSS is hierarchical (hence cascading!) you need to include resets first.

Firstly is [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This applies generally to everything, and is invisible for most purposes. You include the file, everything gets reset to base.

Secondly is [Yahoo UI 3 (YUI) reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), which takes a slightly different approach. They let you selectively apply a reset to different areas of a page by including a class. This is useful for some things, but for almost every small/medium sized project I'd recommend Eric's reset linked above - but it's useful for comparison and learning.

Instead of trying to tune out inconsistencies as you go along - using a CSS reset will give you a baseline for all elements which is the same on every browser. Believe me - **you want this**. When you get further into html, forms for example or fun stuff like that, then this kind of thing is an absolute life saver.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the default padding and margin on any browser. I usually use this:

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: I absolutely dislike * selector. It's slow and overrides to much useful styles. Just pick the elements you need - in this case `body{...}`

Comment: There are far worse bottlenecks than using a * css selector. If you're trying to micro-optimise this way, then it's the wrong approach. Only on very, very limited resource platforms (like, W3C widgets on low end  handsets, for example) do you really need to worry about this.

Comment: @danp - It's not the slowness I object to, it's the sledgehammer approach. The default margins and paddings are a good thing - they encourage learners to select the correct element, especially for headings and paragraphs. Approaches like this, as well as resets like Eric Meyer's destroy that. CSS normalizers are much better.

Comment: ok, when you said it was slow, I thought that was what you were discussing. your other points are valid but debatable. regardless - using a reset is a cast iron industry standard technique, these other approaches are not.